# Custom props in custom widgets of react-jsonschema-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-props, react-jsonschema-forms

I am using react-jsonschema-form and I using my own components as widgets. But I would like to also use my custom component properties like "dropdownType".

Let's say I have override widget diplomas in uiSchema.json like this:

```
"diplomas": {
  "ui:widget": "SelectField",
  "ui:label": false
}
```

And in schema.json I use:

```
   "diplomas": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Obtained diplomas",
      "enum": [
       "ing.",
        "mgr.",
        "bc.",
        "phd.",
        "doc.",
        "prof."
      ]
    }
```

How can I pass my custom component props through react-jsonschema-form? For example I would like to pass

```
"dropdownType": "arrow"
```